# Unzip the contents for the bz2 files via HDFS/Haddop

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

how to unzip a bz2 file in HDFS System wanted to upload this.csv file into a table that i create in hive

2003.csv.bz2 i have this file

zcat 2003.csv.bz2 | hdfs dfs -put - /user/$USER/workspace

this i tried but not working

Answer (score 0):

HDFS can natively store BZ2 files, therefore Hive can read all CSV data in that archive. Ideally, you shouldn't extract it

Or, better, you should convert your CSV to Avro or Parquet **then** upload it. It'll make your Hive queries faster

Otherwise, `hdfs put` accepts files, not an inputstream of text

Comment: got it Thank you @OneCricketeer